# How to get students that are only in selected batch using linq or sql?

Tags: c#, sql, linq, join

I have Students,Batches and StudentBatches tables in my database.Student and respective batches will be there in StudentBatches table like below.

Students

```
ID   Name
1   Student'A'
2   Student'B'
3   Student'C'
4   Student'D'
5   Student'E'
```

Batches

```
ID   Name
1   Batch'A'
2   Batch'B'
3   Batch'C'
```

StudentBatches

```
ID StudentID BatchID
1      1        1
2      2        2
3      2        3
4      3        3
5      4        3
6      5        2
```

My requirement is when I give any batch ID I should get students who are there only in that batch.For example if I give batch Id 3 then I should get 3,4 student ids only because they are not there in any other batch,I should not get 2 student id because that student is also there in batch 2.I hope you understand my requirement.

I have written this query in linq.

```
from batch_student in context.Student_batches
                    group batch_student by batch_student.SID into new_batch_student
                    join student in context.Students on new_batch_student.Key equals student.Id
                    where new_batch_student.Count() == 1 && new_batch_student.Any(x => x.BID == 3)
                    select student;
```

The query is working.But will this have any impact on performance?Is there any query to get that required result?

Comment: What excatly is your problem? Do you want to have suggestions on performance or is your query not working?

Answer (score 1):

Another option would be get rid of grouping and add sub-query

```
  var query = from batch in context.Student_batches
              join student in context.Students on batch.SID equals student.Id
              where batch.BID == 3 && 
                    !context.Student_batches.Any(x => x.SID == student.Id && x.BID != batch.BID)
              select student;
```

See [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/noodIY)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a straightforward approach:

```
var batchID = 3;

var goodStudentIDs = context.Student_batches
    .Where(i => i.BatchID == batchID)
    .Select(i => i.StudentID);

var badStudentIDs = context.Student_batches
    .Where(i => i.BatchID != batchID)
    .Select(i => i.StudentID);

var studentIDs = goodStudentIDs.Except(badStudentIDs);

var students = context.Students.Where(i => studentIDs.Contains(i.ID));
```

You can combine these four statements into a single statement if that is your desire:

```
var batchID = 3;

var students = context.Students
    .Where(i => context.Student_batches
    .Where(j => j.BatchID == batchID)
    .Select(j => j.StudentID)
    .Except(context.Student_batches
    .Where(j => j.BatchID != batchID)
    .Select(j => j.StudentID))
    .Contains(i.ID));
```